# Converting XML string to dataframe in R

Tags: xml, r, url, dataframe, data-science

I am having an issues reading a XML node using R into a data frame. I am new to reading in XML data.

This is what I have managed to get:

```
require(dplyr)
require(rvest)
url <- "http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/177866_49f6965521224dd883df5f20f9c32db3.html"
x <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_node("code") %>%
  html_text() 

x1 <- gsub("##", "", x)
df <- read.table(text = x1, fill = TRUE, sep = "\n", header=TRUE, allowEscapes = TRUE)`
```

However, it seems like read.table() is leaving out some observations and not delimiting some rows.

All I am is get the XML text into a simple data frame. HOpefully I can get some insight on how better to handle this XML stuff.

Comment: There is the suspiciously named `XML` package...

Comment: That page is a pain in the ***.  The data set got wrapped by markdown so it actually ended up stacked.  There's no way you will read it correctly without doing some reconstruction or read 500 lines at a time then bind them.  It looks like there are three sets of 500

Comment: Yes, I know about the XML package and have used it and like the layout of the rvest package better.

I did manage with the lines aboce to read it in and strsplit it with the "\n" delimiter; however, if you look down it looks like 250 lines were separated to a new line with the "\n".

I was going to read it all in and do some transformations. I am just having trouble reading in all 1500 lines seperately and could use some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd split the `pre/code` node into a vector and then read the 3 parts of the table like the comments suggested

```
x1 <- strsplit(x, "\n## *")[[1]]
```

These are fixed width fields, so use `read.fwf` for the first two (the last table does not have any extra spaces)

```
length(x1)
[1] 1503

x1[2]
"1    Espresso Leggero         6        2.54           0            1"

zz <- textConnection(x1[2:501])
df1 <- read.fwf(zz, widths=c(3, 18, 10, 12, 12, 13))
close(zz)
names(df1) <-  c("Id", strsplit(x1[1], " +")[[1]][-1] )
head(df1)
  Id             Flavor Intensity WaterVolume CreamVolume SugarPackets
1  1   Espresso Leggero         6        2.54           0            1
2  2          Ristretto         9        0.85           2            0
3  3          Ristretto         9        0.85           1            3
4  4        Lungo Forte         4        1.35           2            0
5  5      Lungo Leggero         2        0.85           1            1
6  6      Lungo Leggero         2        0.85           2            4

zz <- textConnection(x1[503:1002])
df2 <- read.fwf(zz, widths=c(3, 10, 10, 13, 10, 11, 13) )
close(zz)
names(df2) <- c("Id", strsplit(x1[502], " +")[[1]])

df3 <- read.table(text = x1[1004:1503])
names(df3) <- c("Id", strsplit(x1[1003], " +")[[1]])

coffee <- cbind(df1, df2[,-1], df3[,-1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help Chris S. Worked great!